# Show most popular items of today?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to output all entries of *today*, sorted by the most popular entries (most likes = most popular).

I'm using this query which just selects the most popular entries in the past 24 hours, but if it's 0:00 o'clock for example the count should reset to zero. I also want to order alphabetically if entries have the same count-amount.

How could I achieve that? I tried to `ORDER BY count DESC, p.id DESC` but I think this didn't seem to work using `GROUP BY` I assume.

__

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
p.id, COUNT(l.id) AS count, p.title_de, p.de 
FROM 
pages p 
JOIN pages_likes l on l.page_id = p.id 
WHERE 
l.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND 
l.`status` = 1 GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6
```

This outputs for example:

[image]

Comment: How can **Zocken** come before **Paprika** if alphabetical order is required on same count?

Comment: That's what I want to fix.

Comment: well you put `name desc` is that what you want?

Comment: Then simply add `p.title_de` in order by clause: `ORDER BY count DESC, p.title_de`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want count only the records from current day?

instead of

```
 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Remove the time part with `DATE()`

```
SELECT DATE(NOW());
```

Now the order part: dont use reserved word for alias

```
 SELECT 
       p.id, 
       COUNT(l.id) AS cnt, p.title_de, p.de 

....
ORDER BY cnt DESC,  p.title_de
```

Comment: Why not use the `alias`?

Comment: You are right, is on the `WHERE` where you cant use the alias.